# Link to external pdf that changes file name weekly

Tags: php

I need to link to an external site in my drop down menu that hosts a pdf that changes file name every Friday. I had previously asked this question but I am a beginner to php so I am having a tough time implementing it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Ex.

```
www.extranet.frostyacres.com/portal_resources/1/Market Report 05-24-13.pdf
www.extranet.frostyacres.com/portal_resources/1/Market Report 05-31-13.pdf
www.extranet.frostyacres.com/portal_resources/1/Market Report 06-07-13.pdf
www.extranet.frostyacres.com/portal_resources/1/Market Report 06-14-13.pdf
```

I have tried to use this in a drop down menu in an html file, not sure if thats possible.

```
$startingDate = strtotime('2013-06-07');
echo '<a href="https://www.extranet.frostyacres.com/portal_resources/1/Market Report ' . date('m-d-y', $startingDate) . '.pdf">Market Reports</a>';
```

?

Comment: What have you tried? On what specific part are you stuck? Where is the relevant problem code?

Comment: I have added this php code between the <li> tags of my menu in my index.html file. Do I need to refer to a seperate php file or can I just add the code to the html file?

Comment: And what is the problem with the above code? Doesn't it work? What does it output instead?

Comment: It only links to the start date 06-07-13

Comment: you want links for all fridays since a given start date?

Comment: so briefly you need some loop and you have to substract 7 days from your date in that loop

Comment: @furas What would happen 14 days from now?

Comment: You get last friday as starting date. Starting date - 7 days give you previous friday. Starting date - 14 days give friday two weeks ago. etc. See edelwater answer how to get last friday date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

    // all fridays from startingdate till NOW
    $display_only_the_most_recent_friday = false; // all fridays or most recent only
    $startingDate = strtotime('2013-01-01'); // lets test from start of 2013

    $start = time(); // now
    $end = $startingDate; // our loop will $start from now and scan back till the $end

    // we will check every day from $start to $end
    // in every loop we are going one day back -=(60 * 60 * 24)
    for($checkdate=$start;$checkdate>=$end; $checkdate -=(60 * 60 * 24))
    {
        if ( date('N', $checkdate) == "5" ) // and if this day is the fifth day we echo
        {
            echo '<a href="https://www.extranet.frostyacres.com/portal_resources/1/Market Report '.date('m-d-y', $checkdate).'.pdf">Market Reports</a>';
            if($display_only_the_most_recent_friday)
                break;
        }
    }

?>
```

Its working http://3v4l.org/N3cQW

(it shows newest first)

Comment: Thank you Sharky, I have it in a drop down menu and when I put the php in the menu it has a link for every Friday. How do I have only one link with the pdf from the most recent Friday?

Comment: echo Date('m-d-y', strtotime("Last Friday"));

Comment: @user2276514 if you really want to use my code and display only the recent friday, put a `break;` right after the `echo` so the `for` loop will stop as soon as the first echo occurs. or see the updated answer. i added a variable so you can control it.

Comment: @user2276514 see updated answer. you just need to set `true;` or `false;` on that first variable.

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
echo Date('m-d-y', strtotime("Last Friday"));
```

To display the last friday and then add the amount of times (-7) for the amount of fridays you want to show like so:

```
function display_last_fridays($n) {
    for ($i=0;$i<$n;$i++) {
        echo Date('m-d-y', strtotime($i*-7 . " days Last Friday")) . "<br/>";
    }
}
display_last_fridays(5);
```